# QGIS raster extraction

Tags: qgis, raster, extract

I am attempting to clip a part of Bing Maps Aerial to be able to fine-tune the georeferencing.  I go to "Clip Raster by Extent", & the result is a raster with labels of feature layers embedded in it.  This is even after having the offending layers removed, the project saved, & re-starting QGIS.  Does anyone know a way around this problem?

QGIS 3.12.2-București on Windows 10.0.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that QGIS is capturing labels from layers that do not even exist on your QGIS project? Feels like labels are cached somewhere. What if you add other vector layers into your map, do you get other labels into the output then?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If adding other vector layers with labels they are not appearing in the extracted raster (which is the correct result).

Comment: I've added a clip above of how the extracted raster looks.  I agree with you that it's like the labels are cached somewhere.

Comment: I just tried clearing the cache, & re-extracted the raster, though the result is the same: -Qgis may cache several data without reload from source: authentication settings, connection settings, network settings, raster data. To clear cache go to main menu Settting - Options - Network section Cache settings - Content click basket-button , Authentication click Clear... cache-button